# Iterating result of Select Query

Tags: sql

I have a question related to select query. here I am explaining down below.

I have a table with the following data

```
**Column1(Primary Key)      Column2         Column3**
------                     ---------       --------------
1                             C
2                             C
3                             Null 
4                             H
5                             L 
6                             H
```

my problem is I have to replace the value of **Column3** with the corresponding value of **Column1** for every occurrence of data "C", "H" and "L". Please provide me query related to this problem. How can I solve this using query or stored procedure. Please elaborate the same.

I need final select query result as follows

```
**Column1(Primary Key)      Column2         Column3**
------                     ---------       --------------
1                             C                1
2                             C                2
3                             Null 
4                             H                4
5                             L                5
6                             H                6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Column1, Column2,
CASE
  WHEN Column2 is not null THEN Column1
  ELSE null --or whatever value you want for blank
END as Column3
From TableName t1
```

Alternatively you could it it like this:

```
Select Column1, Column2,
CASE
  WHEN Column2 = 'L' or Column2 = 'H' or Column2 = 'C' THEN Column1
  ELSE null --or whatever value you want for blank
END as Column3
From TableName t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean UPDATE?

```
UPDATE tbl SET Column3 = Column1 WHERE Column2 IN ('C', 'H', 'L', 'F')
```

Or for all;

```
UPDATE tbl SET Column3 = Column1 WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Alex K.: Where did you get the `'F'` from?

Comment: @Alex "I need final select query", "I have a question related to select query"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Column3 = Column1
WHERE Column2 in ('C', 'H', 'L')
```

Answer (score -1):

like this?

```
select Column1, Column2, Column1 as Column3 from table
```

Or I'm not sure what you are actually asking for ..?

Ah, sorry.  Dind't read all of the question there ...

Most SQL dialects have a way to do conditional subselects, but they are different in differend dialects.  So which SQL are you using?